# Problems with connecting postgresql database from docker in go (Windows)

Tags: postgresql, docker, go

I have container with postresql database and can do command in powershell, such as `select * from users` and everything works. But when I try to do this command after connecting this database to GoLang, I always see problem that this relation does not exist.

I create container with database with this method in PowerShell

```bash
docker run -d --name ninja-db -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=goLANGn1nja -v ${HOME}/pgdata_2/:/var/lib/postgresql/data -p 5432:5432 postgres
docker exec -it ninja-db bash
psql -U postgres
create table users (
id serial not null unique,
name varchar(255) not null,
email varchar(255) not null,
password varchar(255) not null,
registered_at timestamp not null default now());
```

and code in go

```golang
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "log"
    "time"
)

type User struct {
    ID           int64
    Name         string
    Email        string
    Password     string
    RegisteredAt time.Time
}

var (
    id   int
    name string
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 user=postgres dbname=postgres sslmode=disable password=12345")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }


    defer db.Close()

    if err := db.Ping(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM users")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    users := make([]User, 0)
    for rows.Next() {
        u := User{}
        err := rows.Scan(&u.ID, &u.Name, &u.Email, &u.Password, &u.RegisteredAt)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        users = append(users, u)
    }

    err = rows.Err()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(users)
}
```

and I tested connection to database with command

```golang
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT 1")
```

and everything works, but when I try to `select * from users` in golang, I always have problem, that relation users doesn't exist.

Comment: In your Go code, the `db.Ping()` works without error, right? Point is that the password there and in the setup commands differ, which throws a doubt on the rest of the info. Make sure that you really include a [mcve] in your question! Also, please provide the output generated by that code, i.e. the full error message.

Comment: Your dbname is wrong it should be refer to the Table that u create (users) but in your connection string in golang u set postgres. So change dbname=postgres to dbname=users

Comment: I tried db.Ping() and it worked, dbname is correct, because I rewrite code from lesson, but he has macOs, maybe it can be reason of problem. Password also correct, because test command rows, err := db.Query("SELECT 1") worked with output 1

Answer (score -1):

try to rewrite query:

```
SELECT * FROM postgres.users
```

Comment: I tried it, but have in console 2024/01/16 10:09:47 pq: relation "postgres.users" does not exist